# Applying SpaCy's EntityRecognizer to a column within a Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nlp, spacy

I have a text based dataset where I am looking to apply SpaCy's EntityRecognizer to each row for a specific column.

I can apply the general spaCy pipeline by doing something like this:

df['new_col'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: nlp(x))

How do I just apply just the entity recongnizer and get its values?

Answer (score 4):

In Spacy a doc have a attribute `.ents` witch return a generator on its named entities.

So you can use :

```
df['new_col'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: list(nlp(x).ents))
```

Comment: This works. Is there a way to call in the _label of that entity and add that as an additional column?

Comment: I guess you can do the following: `df['new_col'] = df['col'].apply(lambda x: list(nlp(x).label_))`