# Is there a way to run spaCy NER on a field of a JSON file?

Tags: python, json, spacy

I am trying to analyze with spaCy (geographical) entities that appear in a field of a JSON file `json-capLatLong.json`. The file looks like this:

```json
[{
    "caption": "Grassland north of Eastdon ",
    "ground truth toponym": "Eastdon",
    "guide-latitude-WGS84": "50.611614",
    "guide-longitude-WGS84": "-3.447207",
    "disambiguated": "Eastdon, Teignbridge, Devon, South West England, England, EX6 8RH, United Kingdom"
}, {
    "caption": "Wall north of Hulne Park ",
    "ground truth toponym": "Hulne Park",
    "guide-latitude-WGS84": "55.446522",
    "guide-longitude-WGS84": "-1.748779",
    "disambiguated": "Hulne Park, Denwick, Alnwick, Northumberland, North East England, England, United Kingdom"
}, {
    "caption": "Farm track north of Aglionby ",
    "ground truth toponym": "Aglionby",
    "guide-latitude-WGS84": "54.908579",
    "guide-longitude-WGS84": "-2.866381",
    "disambiguated": "Aglionby, Carlisle, Cumbria, North West England, England, CA4 8AJ, United Kingdom"
}, {
    "caption": "Long barrow north of Martin ",
    "ground truth toponym": "Martin",
    "guide-latitude-WGS84": "50.98477",
    "guide-longitude-WGS84": "-1.910483",
    "disambiguated": "Martin, Hampshire, South East, England, SP6 3LF, United Kingdom"
}, {
    "caption": "A483 north of Pool Quay ",
    "ground truth toponym": "Pool Quay",
    "guide-latitude-WGS84": "52.701294",
    "guide-longitude-WGS84": "-3.098761",
    "disambiguated": "Pool Quay, Powys, Wales, SY21 9JS, United Kingdom"
}, {
    "caption": "Power line north of Dagnets Lane ",
    "ground truth toponym": "Dagnets Lane",
    "guide-latitude-WGS84": "51.846349",
    "guide-longitude-WGS84": "0.537283",
    "disambiguated": "Dagnets Lane, Black Notley, Braintree, Essex, East of England, England, CM77 8QP, United Kingdom"
}, {
    "caption": "Fields north of Ellington ",
    "ground truth toponym": "Ellington",
    "guide-latitude-WGS84": "52.347205",
    "guide-longitude-WGS84": "-0.291146",
    "disambiguated": "Ellington, Cambridgeshire, East of England, England, United Kingdom"
}, {
    "caption": "Fields north of Belsey Bridge Road ",
    "ground truth toponym": "Belsey Bridge Road",
    "guide-latitude-WGS84": "52.479252",
    "guide-longitude-WGS84": "1.428283",
    "disambiguated": "Belsey Bridge Road, Ditchingham, South Norfolk, Norfolk, East of England, England, NR35 2DT, United Kingdom"
}, {
    "caption": "Pasture north of Balhomish ",
    "ground truth toponym": "Balhomish",
    "guide-latitude-WGS84": "56.544822",
    "guide-longitude-WGS84": "-3.605378",
    "disambiguated": "Balhomish, Inver, Perth and Kinross, Scotland, PH8 0DX, United Kingdom"
}, {
    "caption": "The A22 north of South Godstone ",
    "ground truth toponym": "South Godstone",
    "guide-latitude-WGS84": "51.222992",
    "guide-longitude-WGS84": "-0.04726",
    "disambiguated": "South Godstone, Surrey, South East, England, RH9 8HS, United Kingdom"
}, {
    "caption": "Farm on track east of Hardwick",
    "ground truth toponym": "Hardwick",
    "guide-latitude-WGS84": "51.866063",
    "guide-longitude-WGS84": "-0.826492",
    "disambiguated": "Hardwick, Buckinghamshire, South East, England, HP22 4DX, United Kingdom"
}, {
    "caption": "Un-named lane east of Clare",
    "ground truth toponym": "Clare",
    "guide-latitude-WGS84": "51.681005",
    "guide-longitude-WGS84": "-1.02134",
    "disambiguated": "Clare, South Oxfordshire, Oxfordshire, South East, England, OX9 7HF, United Kingdom"
}]
```

and I am interested in analyzing the `caption` column.

I know how to handle a string, i.e. with something along the lines of

```
import spacy
import json

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

doc = nlp("Grassland north of Eastdon")

for ent in doc.ents:

    print(ent.text, ent.label_)
    # this gives me in output "Grassland GPE"
```

so to extract all the FAC, GPE or LOC in the input string.
How can I handle all the JSON file though?

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.  Your posted code does not run, due to the syntax error in the `doc =` line.

Comment: If all you want is the series of phrases listed as `caption`, then why are you using `spacy` at all?  That's a simple JSON load to a dict, followed by iterating through the dict.  You can find this in any tutorial on the JSON package.

Answer (score 0):

One starting point could be something along the lines of

```py
import pandas as pd
import spacy

df = pd.read_json("json-capLatLong.json")

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")

def get_toponyms(caption):
  return [e.text for e in nlp(caption).ents if e.label_ in ["GPE", "FAC", "LOC"]]

df["extracted toponyms"] = df.caption.apply(get_toponyms)
print(df["extracted toponyms"])
```

The idea is to read in your json with pandas, and then apply NER to the `caption` field/column, as in [Applying SpaCy's EntityRecognizer to a column within a Pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51432641/applying-spacys-entityrecognizer-to-a-column-within-a-pandas-dataframe)

The list comprehension in `get_toponyms` filters only the text corresponding to geographical entities.

However, I am afraid that recall of your ground truth will be low, possibly as some of those toponyms are not "known" to the model. Using a larger model (e.g. `en_core_web_lg`) may help increase recall a bit.

Comment: @DuelistPlayer I had a shot at this in case that's helpful, please clarify the question (title included...) as it's not very clear as it stands. What it the expected output exactly? Something close to `ground truth toponym` starting from the `caption`? That's what I assumed...

Comment: Well, the topic relates to the use of spatial databases and the task is this:

"The task requires the use of the SpaCy named entity recognition function to detect the presence of the place names in each caption. You are provided with a json file called json-capLatLong.json that lists the photo caption, the ground truth toponym, the guide coordinates as latitude and longitude and the full address of the disambiguated toponym for each caption"

Comment: The above relates to this question:

Detect place names (toponyms) in the provided captions using the default SpaCy Named Entity Recognition interpretation of place names (i.e. as any FAC, GPE or LOC). Run the SpaCy NER software to detect all entities that are classified as some form of geographic feature, i.e. FAC, GPE or LOC.

I'm somewhat familiar with how to run text files through Spacy to get the geographical features but I'm familiar with how I can do it with a JSON file.